# How do I auto-mount internal HDD partitions to dynamic mount points?

Tags: automounting

I would like to auto-mount some partitions the way USB drives and external HDDs are currently mounted on my system.

I understand that to auto-mount internal HDDs at startup, I need to place it in the `/etc/fstab` and map its mount point, etc. But I like how my USB drives and external HDDs are automatically mounted to `/run/media/myuser/drive-label` when I plug them in.

To do this to my internal HDDs, I'd have to use `udiskctl mount --block-device /dev/sda4` and it then gets mounted to `/run/media/myuser/sda4-label`. Is there a way of doing it automatically on boot?

*I'm currently using Antergos (Arch Linux)*

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the AutoFS service which can facilitate more elaborate automounting scenarios than can be accomplished via the `/etc/fstab` file.

- [AutoFS - ArchLinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/autofs)

You can do a variety of things such as automounting devices via a script, when a directory path is accessed.

```
/media/ssh      /etc/autofs/auto.ssh    --timeout=60
```

In this scenario if someone were to access `/media/ssh` the script `/etc/autofs/auto.ssh` would execute and "mount" whatever directory they attempted to access under `/media/ssh`.

```
# /etc/autofs/auto.ssh
servername     -fstype=fuse,rw,allow_other,IdentityFile=/home/username/.ssh/id_dsa :sshfs\#username@host\:/
```

After 60 secs. of inactivity `autofs` will unmount the directory.