# How to auto-mount HDD within encrypted /home partition/directory?

Tags: ubuntu, mount, home, automounting, ecryptfs

My machine has a secondary (NTFS-formatted) internal hard disk drive containing most of my personal files and data. I wish to auto-mount this drive under my user HOME. However, during installation of Ubuntu (17.10), I chose to create a separate /home partition and apply the default (`ecryptfs`) encryption. This appears to be preventing the HDD from auto-mounting as desired from the entry I've created in `fstab`. However, the drive happily auto-mounts to un-encrpyted directories.

How can I achieve auto-mounting of the secondary hard drive under `/home/<username>/`?

I believe auto-mounting with `fstab` occurs during boot, while `/home` isn't decrypyted until user login. Perhaps the relevant `fstab` entry could be automatically checked *after* login? Perhaps I could create a small post-login script to automatically run the `mount` command - but I believe this would require a `sudo` password prompt (or maybe I should try the [AutoFS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/116236/how-do-i-auto-mount-internal-hdd-partitions-to-dynamic-mount-points) tool). Or, since `ecryptfs` is a stacked filesystem, perhaps I could change the mount point be in the lower, encrypted layer which, if I understand correctly, is under `/user/<username>/.Private`? Since this layer is persistent, it exists through boot - but I can't imagine what would happen from attempting to mount an un-encrypted NTFS filesystem there.

Comment: You don't need `sudo` (or any other thing giving you rootpermissions if you add `user` to the list of options in `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that this is a personal system.  Mount the drive external to your home folder and use a symbolic link to join the drive to your home folder.

```
ln -s <target> <localname>
```

so if the drive is mounted at

```
/mnt/ntfsdrive
```

and you want it in your home folder as ndfsdrive,

```
ln -s /mnt/ntfsdrive /home/<username>/ntfsdrive
```

If this is not a personal or physically secured system, then other security considerations come into play.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned I am already aware of the symlink solution and am not against it - but I am interested to learn of any mount-based solutions.